# Can I use an extension *member* from outside the class?

Tags: kotlin, extension-function

If I have an extension function for type A declared inside class B:

```
class A

class B {
    fun A.foo() = "Hello"
}
```

Can I call this function at all from code that is outside class B?

```
val a = A()
val b = B()
a.foo()      // error: unresolved reference: foo
b.foo()      // error: unresolved reference: foo
```

Comment: This code doesn't even look like it will compile.  Granted, I'm not a Kotlin expert, but... maybe you could show a bit more code?  Does Kotlin have access modifiers you've forgotten to include?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the first part will definitely compile. The second part won't since the extension method `A.foo` isn't in the global scope like the error says.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the only part that doesn't compile is where I said there would be errors: https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLVJDIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJmb2xkZWRCdXR0b24iOnRydWUsInJlYWRPbmx5IjpmYWxzZSwiY29kZSI6ImNsYXNzIEFcblxuY2xhc3MgQiB7XG4gICAgZnVuIEEuZm9vKCkgPSBcIkhlbGxvXCJcbn1cblxudmFsIGEgPSBBKClcbnZhbCBiID0gQigpXG5hLmZvbygpXG5iLmZvbygpIn0=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
with(b) { 
    a.foo() 
}
```

Other functions accepting a lambda with a `B` receiver would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, when you've defined A.foo inside B, you've effectively scoped the function to the class. However, you can always move it outside the class... functions can be top-level also :)

Comment: Actually yes, you can.